# Использование "красивых" стилей элементов окна

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

Пытаюсь в окне сделать кнопку.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HFONT hFont;
    HWND hButton;
    switch(message) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hButton = CreateWindow("button", "Press me!",
                               WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
                               5, 5, 100, 100,
                               hWnd, (HMENU)(1),
                               (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, -6), NULL);
        hFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
        SendMessage(hButton, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, 1);
        return 0 ;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

Получается такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как сделать кнопку, по стилю как в остальных приложениях (такую, например: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]). Система Windows 7, компилятор gcc.exe (tdm64-1) 5.1.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действительно, как сказал Abyx, надо было добавить манифест (я надеялся, что есть путь проще). В итоге порядок действий:

1. Создать файл `Application.manifest` (например в директории с `main.c`):

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
       <assemblyIdentity
           version="1.0.0.0"
           processorArchitecture="*"
           name="Button"
           type="win32"
       />
       <description>Just button.</description>
       <dependency>
           <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity
                   type="win32"
                   name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
                   version="6.0.0.0"
                   processorArchitecture="*"
                   publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
                   language="*"
               />
           </dependentAssembly>
       </dependency>
   </assembly>
   ```
2. Создать файл ресурсов `resources.rc` в той же директории, что и манифест, в которой будет одна строка:

   ```
   1 24 "Application.manifest"
   ```
3. Далее нужно скомпилировать файл ресурсов (выполнить команду в командной строке):

   ```
   windres resources.rc -o resources.o
   ```
4. Нужно добавить некоторый код в `main.cpp`:

   ```
   #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 //для запуска нужна система Vista или новее
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <commctrl.h>
   int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
       INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
       icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
       icex.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
       InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);
       /* Далее код создания окна и все остальное */
   }
   ```
5. Ну и теперь нужно непосредственно скомпилировать программу (естественно надо не забыть про библиотеку):

   ```
   g++ -o program.exe main.cpp resources.o -lcomctl32 -mwindows
   ```

Comment: В пункте 2 что создать? И почему нужна виста, если манифесты были в XP?

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, не заметил, во втором пункте поправил, должно было быть "Создать файл ресурсов resources.rc". А виста, так как `InitCommonControlsEx` появилась только в висте, судя по MSDN.

Comment: А как использовать манифест в XP? Это же точно возможно.